# Changing a variable in the database on a set time

Tags: php

I am making an auction website, where users can add products, and set the end date.

My table enddate is like: 2015-2-25 14:01:23
and to determine if the item is ended I have a row called ended which can be 0 or 1. While I am writing this, I am thinking maybe I should check if time(system) is after or before enddate row to determine if the item is ended...

Anyway How would I go about changing the row ended to 1 on the exact time and date (even if someone's not  viewing the page to run an ajax script) Would I have to do chron, or would it be better if I done what I mentioned above regarding checking the times?

Which one would you recommend? If using row ended how would I accomplish updating this on the enddate time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, that's not the way to use a database. Your own suggestion is the way to go: Check if the current time is after or before enddate row to determine if the item has ended...